# Why no output after Dataset.mapPartitions (stopping data in downstream stream processing)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming and am facing problems with `mapPartitions`.

If we comment `foreach` operation inside `mapPartitions` it works just fine.

spark ui is showing job complete

[image]

```
stream
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
  .map { data => MetricDataFilter.filter_metric_data(data._1, data._2) }
  .mapPartitions { partition =>
    val lagged = partition.filter { x => x.metric_type == "n" }
    lagged.foreach { x =>
      val diff = Instant.now().toEpochMilli - x.timestamp.getTime
      println(x.toString)
      println(diff)
    }
    partition
  }
  .filter($"metric_type" === "c")
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 minutes")
  .groupBy(
    window($"timestamp", "30 seconds", "30 seconds"),
    $"metric_name", $"timestamp")
  .sum("metric_value").as("sum_metric_value")
  .writeStream
  .queryName("countMetricQuery")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
  .format("console")
  .start
```

removing `foreach` in `mapPartitions` works fine.

```
lagged.foreach {
              x =>
                val diff = Instant.now().toEpochMilli - x.timestamp.getTime
                diff > 0 match {
                  case false =>
                    println(x.toString)
                  case true => println(x.toString)
                }
                println(diff)

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very tricky issue to spot and is due to how `Iterator` works in Scala.

The following is the signature of `mapPartitions` which says that you work with `Iterator[T]`.

> **mapPartitions[U](func: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]**
>
> Returns a new Dataset that contains the result of applying func to each partition.

`scala.Iterator` is a single-pass data structure so once all elements are consumed they're simply gone.

See yourself:

```
scala> val it = Seq(1,2,3).toIterator
it: Iterator[Int] = <iterator>

scala> it.foreach(println)
1
2
3

scala> it.foreach(println)
```

As you can see nothing's printed out in the second `foreach` as no elements were left to consume.

In other words, your streaming query has no data left to process after `mapPartitions` and hence no output.